# Cython runtests.py: no attribute 'may_share_memory'

Tags: python, windows, module, installation, cython

I installed cython on Windows (running python(x,y)) by downloading it from http://cython.org/ and I ran

```
python setup.py install
```

in the installation directory. There is a testmodule "runtests.py" in the installation folder and it gives the error message

```
may_share_memory = multiarray.may_share_memory
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'may_share_memory'
```

How can I make the error go away?

UPDATE: It seems my numpy-version was the reason for this error. I have downloaded numpy again from the python(x,y) website (https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/wiki/StandardPlugins) and the error disappeared.

Comment: Perhaps you should close the question.